# How can i change the color per section in this line chart?

Tags: d3.js, linechart

So I am trying to do this chart

[image: Line Chart 1]

And I have this at this moment

[image: Line Chart 2]

I need to do this simple thing, with the data put this colored background

[image: Line Chart 1 example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have an x axis set up, perhaps you could do something like this (adjust as necessary if you're using v5):

```js
var overlays = [[0, 10], [30, 60]];

svg.selectAll('rect.overlay')
  .data(overlays)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'overlay')
  .attr('x', d => x(d[0])) // place the rectangle on the x axis based on the start point
  .attr('width', d => x(d[1]) - x(d[0])) // calculate the width
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('fill', '#00000022');
```

Comment: So i did something with this, the problem is that it doesn´t mark an entire area or mark from a certain date to date

svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.DATE); })
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Dato); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Dato); })
        .style("fill", "#010101")
        .style("opacity", "0.1");

Comment: What does the data look like? If `data` is the data you're using to construct your line graph, it probably won't work for making these grey areas. You will need to have some data with a start date and an end date, to denote the area that should be marked. Right now you have a `width` of `20`, so the shaded areas are always going to be 20px wide regardless of the data.  



You also probably don't need to use the `y` axis at all in your `y` and `height` functions, since you want the whole area to be covered. Instead, `y` should be 0, and `height` should be the height of your chart area.

Comment: i understand, and yes the data that i am using is the same to construct the line graph, i did the bar chart inside the line graph but the thing that i need is that it start from a date to other and fill all that time with that color, the only thing that i achieved was making bars but not with the correct width, i will try again to the what happens, thanks!!